# Position a fixed child relative to a parent's parent

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

So I made one small_window inside a browser window, inside it a smaller_window that holds some auto-scrolling text.

And I also want some text in smaller_window to stay static and to NOT scroll inside smaller_window. So here pos_fixed is absolute and relative to small_window.

```
<header>
<style type="text/css">
.small_window{
    position:relative;
}

#smaller_window{
    height:470px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position: initial !important; /* I expect this would make pos_fixed a child of small_window instead of smaller_window */
}

p.pos_fixed {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
right: 30px;
}
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div id="small_window">
    <div id="smaller_window">
        <p class="pos_fixed">This line is fixed relative to smaller_window</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And it works like a charm on Firefox38 and IE11.
However, I doubt its cross-browser compatibility since my mobile browser (chrome mobile) still positions pos_fixed relative to smaller_window, apparently having ignored

```
#smaller_window{
    position: initial !important; 
}
```

Any suggestion on a better cross-browser compatible way to position a fixed child relative to parent's parent?

Comment: That's better. The coding was awfull...

Answer (score 0):

You not adding class for smaller_window but you writing id for smaller_window in css how it will work? can u post your code in fiddle??